# Polymorphism? Inheritance? How to do it?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

**EDIT:** I know it is a little strange design, and so it is difficult to answer. It Is FlowChart diagram on the picture. Every class represents some type of component used in this flowChart. But now I made much more clearer solution of my problem. The question is no more actual.//end EDIT

Hello, I have a small problem which I dont know how to solve. I have three classes, every of them can have many instances. See the picture.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d0e6080285.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d0e6080285.jpg)

1)InstanceOfClass1 provides array of booleans to instanceOfClass3 going OUT of instanceOfClass1.(see the arrows on the pic)

2)Every other instanceOfClass3 has the identical array of boolean (only in the tree on the picture, there can be more trees in app

3)all booleans in provided array are false.

I need to know how to do this: When I set one boolean in one instanceOfClass3 to true, how to disable setting this one boolean to true in other instances of class 3?

Comment: Why was this tagged functional-programming?

Comment: I think a little more explanation of what you are trying to achieve might be required.  I honestly have no idea.  What kind of diagram is that and what is it supposed to represent?

Comment: Looks like a flowchart used as an object diagram... inventive, in its own way ;-)

Comment: Object attributes are by definition bound to an instance and do not link between instances. Hence your questions does not seem to make sense

Comment: What are the meanings of the different polygons? What relationship do the arrows signify? What is the significance of the arrow labels? The diagram isn't following any standard that I'm aware of. Without knowing the meaning of the symbols, the diagram is meaningless.

Comment: @Péter Torok
yes, it is flow chart diagram. Because every instance of an class represents a component of flowchart.

Comment: @joseph: I still can't make sense of the diagram. Flowcharts model processes: shapes represent actions and arrows represent transitions (control flow); both are essentially verbs. Objects, however, are nouns. Even though the question is moot, I'm still curious what you intended the diagram to mean.

Comment: @joseph I understand this might look clear to you, but it is very puzzling for most of us. Boxes in flow charts are supposed to represent states and decision points in a process, not class objects - those are typically shown on object diagrams. If you use well known diagrams in an unconventional way, you make it difficult for yourself to communicate your mental model with others. If you want to learn more about UML, the de facto standard, here is a tutorial: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite clear what you are looking for... I can only guess.

If you are sharing those arrays between your objects, any change you make in the array will be naturally visible in any object which holds a reference to it.

If you do not want the changes to propagate, you must create a separate copy of your array in each object.

Comment: Wow, well done on getting the accepted answer to that question.  I still don't get what the problem to be solved was.

Comment: Even so - if that array is in a global state / singleton, I start questioning the design.

Comment: @DaveJohnston Sometimes my wild guess works, with a bit of luck :-) @Kevin McKelvin I agree that there is a lot to be questioned in this design, however the OP seems to have more fundamental problems here...